# How can I create a line that joins two dots?

Tags: flutter

I have four dots and I want to create a line by joining 2 dots horizontally and vertically only. How can I achieve this with flutter?

[image: These are dots in image]

Here is my code:

`````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Grid4 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10),
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 25,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white70, shape: BoxShape.circle)),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 5,
            mainAxisSpacing: 40,
            crossAxisSpacing: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

````
`````

Comment: Actually I want to make simple dot and box game ..
So, I am talking about that joinning when a player touches a dot and can draw a line when he reaches another dot .

I hope I am able to make you undertand what I want.

Comment: So, again I'll ask, is it the touch input or the drawing that you need help with? What touch input or drawing methods have you tried using so far?

Comment: I know the GestureDetector method as touch input and first I am confused that where I should specify this touch input in my code.( i m adding my code here)

Second I don't know anything about drawing so you can help me with that

Comment: Why do you have to make game with non-game tool?

Comment: @SaadAnees I am asked to do so

Comment: Making an Idle game would be easier. Also some sort of simulation games might be more appropriate for flutter. For example see screenshots from Bygfoot and you will see what i mean.

Comment: Also after little searching the web reveals that action games under flutter are possible. https://blog.geekyants.com/building-a-2d-game-in-flutter-a-comprehensive-guide-913f647846bc

Comment: Yeah action games are possible under flutter and I didnt get what Is Bygfoot ?